# string.split returning array with 1 element

Tags: javascript, wordpress

In a Wordpress's page, the string.split is returning an array with just 1 element containing the complete string instead of splitting it into several elements.

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1/?mouses=razer&micros";
if (url.indexOf("?mouses=") != -1){
  var mouses_substr = url.substring(url.indexOf('?mouses=') + 8);
  var mouses_array = mouses_substr.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i<mouses_array.length; i++) {
    alert(mouses_array[i]+"<br>");
  }
}
```

In this case the

```
mouses_array
```

should output

```
razer
```

in the first alert box and

```
micros
```

for the second.

Instead its giving me

```
razer&micros
```

There is not point using str.split since it is not splitting anything. Any fixes / workarounds?

Comment: When I run the code, I get two `alert`s - "razer<br>" and then "micros<br>" - http://jsfiddle.net/n48H6/ (which seems to contradict what you're claiming, and produces what you want/expect)

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) working demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar? Because the problem you describe seems unlikely (and is contradicted by @Ian, above).